# Surface of revolution without touching the axis of revolution is regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

I read that the surface of revolution is a regular surface when it does not touch the axis of revolution. But why it cannot touch the axis of revolution? For example, I can generate a sphere by touching the endpoints of my semicircle curve and a sphere is a regular surface.

What is the condition required so that a surface of revolution which touches the axis of revolution but still a regular surface?

Comment: "the surface of revolution is a regular surface when it does not touch the axis of revolution" is not wrong. Intuitively, your condition is that the curve is normal to the axis where they meet otherwise your curve is not differentiable at that point.

Comment: what do you mean by the curve is normal to the axis where they meet? Do you mind to elaborate more on this? @Paul

Comment: Perpendicular to, orthogonal to, at right angles to.

Comment: you mean the tangent vector of the curve is orthogonal to the axis?
@Paul

Comment: Sam thing, yes.

Comment: does it have something to do with the "cusp"? @Paul

Comment: Yes, a regular surface has a tangent plane everywhere (so that a 2D cross section has a tangent line). See for example http://uregina.ca/~mareal/cs3.pdf